# Error with Counter increment for products in loop vue 3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i have an issue with the counter when an increment or decrement is made the products in the loop will all increment yet the product in the first index is the one being increment i have reproduced this error.

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
  export default{
    setup() {
       const count = ref(1);
       const increment = async() => {
          count.value ++;
       }
       const decrement = async()=> {
          count.value --;
       }
       const products = ref(
       [
         {id:1,name:"Product1"}, 
         {id:2,name:"Product2"},
         {id:3,name:"Product3"},
         {id:4,name:"Product4"}
       ]
       );
       return{
         products,
         count,
         increment,
         decrement
       }
    }
  }

</script>

<template>
    <div v-for="item in products" :key="item.id">
        <p> {{ item. name }}</p> 
        <button @click="increment"> + </button>
              {{ count }}
        <button @click="decrement"> - </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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

I want counter to increase for only one product

Answer (score 1):

here the answer you looking for? You can do this add a new **count variable** in your array. Count is loop by array Try this >>> [Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
  export default{
    setup() {
       //const count = ref(1);
       const increment = async(index) => {
         products.value[index].count++;
       }
       const decrement = async(index)=> {
          products.value[index].count--;
       }
       const products = ref(
       [
         {id:1,name:"Product1", count:0}, 
         {id:2,name:"Product2", count:0},
         {id:3,name:"Product3", count:0},
         {id:4,name:"Product4", count:0}
       ]
       );
       return{
         products,
         //count,
         increment,
         decrement
       }
    }
  }

</script>

<template>
    <div v-for="(item,index) in products" :key="item.id">
        <p> {{ item. name }}</p> 
        <button @click="increment(index)"> + </button>
              {{ item.count }}
        <button @click="decrement(index)"> - </button>
  </div>
</template>
```